# Get *all* current jobs from python-rq

Tags: python, python-rq

I'm using python-rq to manage Redis-based jobs and I want to determine which jobs are currently being processed by my workers.

python-rq offers a get_current_job function to find 'the current job' for a connection but:

1. I can't get this to work, and
2. I really want a list of *all* of the jobs which are being currently processed by *all* workers on *all* the queues for this connection rather than *one* job from *one* queue.

Here is my code (which always returns None):

```
from rq import Queue, get_current_job
redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_FOO')
parse.uses_netloc.append('redis')
url = parse.urlparse(redis_url)
conn = Redis(host=url.hostname, port=url.port, db=0, password=url.password)
q = Queue(connection=conn)
get_current_job(connection=conn)
```

Does anyone have any ideas, please, on getting the above code to work but, more importantly, on a way to get a list of all current jobs from all workers on all queues from this connection?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looked into some source code, I figure this what you need:

[image]

There is one more thing you should notice: the number of the running jobs is equal to the number of rq worker. Because worker only process one job at a time.

```
from rq import Queue
from redis import Redis
from rq.registry import StartedJobRegistry

from jobs import count_words_at_url


redis_conn = Redis()
q = Queue('default', connection=redis_conn)

for i in range(5000):
    job = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://nvie.com', ttl=43)

registry = StartedJobRegistry('default', connection=redis_conn)

running_job_ids = registry.get_job_ids()  # Jobs which are exactly running. 
expired_job_ids = registry.get_expired_job_ids()
```

Comment: [...] the number of the running jobs is _equal to or less than_ the number of rq workers.

Comment: If you are looking for the queued job id's you can go for `queued_job_ids = registry.get_queue().job_ids`